# MemoryException due to CString concatenation (?) without operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management, crash, c-strings

My application is crashing on following line of source code:

```
CString path;
path = CACHE_DIR _T("Local\\Alarm\\current.tmp");
```

Where:

```
#define CACHE_DIR       _T("C:\\<somewhere>\\System Cache\\")
```

The callstack mentions following line of code:

```
mfc140u.dll!ATL::CSimpleStringT<wchar_t,1>::operator=(const wchar_t * pszSrc) Line 317
```

I tried to do some analysis, trying to use the immediate window, but this does not recognise the `_T()` operator, nor its synonyms `__T()` or `L ##`.

So now, it seems that I have two possible causes:

1. The concatenation goes wrong (question: is it correct concatenating two `CString` objects simply by putting them one after the other in a single line of source code?).
2. The result of the concatenation is good, but I can't put it in the result variable, which is caused by:

   2.1. A wrong way to handle a `CString` variable.

   2.2. A memory issue, which has nothing to do with this particular line of source code (but why does my application then keep crashing exactly on this line?).

For your information, my application is multi-threaded.

Can anybody tell me what's going wrong in my application?

**Edit after first comments:**
The source seems to be correct, which might indicate a heap corruption, but I have no idea on how to investigate the heap. Does anybody have any clues on that matter?

Comment: _Can anybody tell me what's going wrong in my application?_ Not without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You're not concatenating two CStrings in the posted code. Those are string literals, the compiler concatenates them into a single literal. My money is on a memory issue caused elsewhere that has corrupted the heap the dynamic string allocator in ATL's CString is using during it's assignment operator. That's a guess, and likely the best you'll get without an [mcve].

Comment: Do some research on debugging ATL/MFC memory corruption tracking. The runtime debug allocator will probably be part of that, and is pretty elaborate in its capabilities. It's far more than can be described here. Fair warning though, it's complex, so pour the coffee.

Comment: To investigate heap corruption you just have to guess where the program is failing, it might be totally unrelated to `CString` or that particular line. Compile with level 4 warning might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the "cause" of the issue: in order to solve a previous issue, I'd enabled all gflags of my computer, but I had forgotten to disable them afterwards.

I've now disabled all gflags, and now the problem does not occur anymore:
Lanuch "Application Verifier", and configure it as follows:

[image]